# Array manipulation issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, math

I seem to be having a brain fart. I need to get the diff from average for an array of arrays. This is part math, and part data formatting, so any help would be appreciated.

The original dataset I have here:

```
[
    {"key":"a4","values":[[1426963465929,676],[1426963465957,676][1426963465992,676],[1426963466025,676],[1426963466057,676],[1426963466088,676],[1426963466120,676],[1426963466150,676],[1426963466183,676],[1426963466214,676],[1426963466247,676],[1426963466283,676],[1426963466317,676],[1426963466351,676],[1426963466388,676],[1426963466422,676],[1426963466454,676],[1426963466485,675.5],[1426963466516,676],[1426963466548,676]],"tempDisabled":false,"seriesIndex":0},{"key":"a5","values":[[1426963465928,561],[1426963465956,563],[1426963465990,563.5],[1426963466024,562],[1426963466055,561],[1426963466087,562.5],[1426963466119,564],[1426963466149,563.5],[1426963466181,561],[1426963466212,562],[1426963466245,563.5],[1426963466281,564],[1426963466315,562],[1426963466350,561.5],[1426963466386,563.5],[1426963466420,563],[1426963466452,561],[1426963466484,562],[1426963466514,564],[1426963466546,563.5]],"tempDisabled":false,"seriesIndex":1}]
```

I need to get the average of both the data[0].values[1] and data[1].values[1] separately.

Then I need to create data[2] & data[3] with values of the difference from the average from both data[0].values and data[1].values in the same format.

so for example, I need the end result for data[2].values to be:

```
[
    [1426963465929,0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465957, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963465992, 0.026315789473642326],
    [1426963466485,-0.4736842105263577]
]
```

Where data[2].values[n][1] is the difference from the average from all the original data[0].values[n][1] numbers plus the millisecond time of the data entry in data[0].values[n][0]

Hopefully that is clear enough? 
Don't spend to much time on it if you can't solve it. I am just messing around with visualizing Arduino Gyro data through nvd3 (arduino->johnny-five->firebase->angular-nvd3)

This is a visualization of the original data with 1000 data points for data[0] and data[1]. As you can see, it is pretty useless without noise reduction, and I really just want to see the movement by itself.

*Nevermind, not enough reputation to post an image :( *

Comment: You should label the fields you are trying to compute and then write the pseudocode for what they are. Working with random fields called data[0] and data[1].values[0] is super confusing. Break it down into small clearly labeled steps that you can verify along the way. This is less a question of 'how to' and more a request for someone to write code for you.

Comment: When I get back to my pc, I will fill out each piece. Sorry mate! No interest in having someone solve for me. Just need to figure out out how to start solving this problem.

Comment: Hey no need to apologize :), just want to help out but am a bit unsure which part in particular is the issue.